# Read Strings separated by newline using BufferedReader into a String array

Tags: java, regex, string, bufferedreader

I've read number of such questions but they are all about reading inputs from a `txt` file. I want to read input from user and not from the file.

I've input like following:

```
6   //number of total Strings to store in array 
babu   
anand
rani    
aarti
nandu
rani
```

I've tried the following code to take such input in a `String` array:

```
    int n = in.nextInt();    // n= 6 here
    String[] s = new String[n];   //String array of size 6 here
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try{
         s = br.readLine().split("\\s");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Is the `regex` provided to the `split()` is correct or not? What I'm missing here? If this is not correct approach than what should I do for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Regex are using backslashes (`\`) while you used slashes `//s`, correct one is `\\s`.

But this split is not needed, you just need the `readLine`, and you will get what you need (assuming you don't want to split words in the line).

You should use a loop to read all the data (and get rid of Scanner, that you appear to have in the `in` variable):

```
String[] s = null
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for (int line = 0; line < n; line++) {
        s[line] = br.readLine();
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);       
}
```

Comment: but when i print the array nothing is printed and it gives arrayOutOfBoundsException at index 1.

Comment: if i use just readLine() than i can't store it directly in array

Comment: @Kaushal28 You don't want? OK, so you need to read the whole data into a large String and then you can do `split` on the whole string.

Comment: but I've done the same for space separated Strings. Why I cant do this for newline separated strings?

Comment: I used "s = in.readLine().split(" ");" for space separated strings

Comment: Because you are using `readLine`, which is ... reading a single line

Comment: @Kaushal28 `readLine()` also strips the newline character out of the returned string so you will never be able to use a regex to find the newline.

Comment: oh. You are right. So it is impossible by splitting new lines?

Comment: @Kaushal28 You would need to read the whole user input into a big String and then do the splitting, which is not very efficient (use e.g IOUtils.toString from apache commons library).

Comment: so what is the fastest method for this? I am using BufferedReader instead of Scanner here to fast inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Move the third line before the first one.

Then use this in your new second line:

int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

And, of course, you need a loop to put your input strings into an array.

This should help.